# getmxrr not working in Windows

Tags: php, dns, php-7

I am using this simple code

```
getmxrr("google.com", $res);
var_dump($res);
```

In windows, I am getting `null`,

while on Ubuntu, I am getting:

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(23) "alt4.aspmx.l.google.com"
  [1] =>
  string(18) "aspmx.l.google.com"
  [2] =>
  string(23) "alt3.aspmx.l.google.com"
  [3] =>
  string(23) "alt1.aspmx.l.google.com"
  [4] =>
  string(23) "alt2.aspmx.l.google.com"
}
```

Both use PHP 7.0.x

Comment: Having exactly the same problem!

On Windows
`php -r '$mxHosts = [];$weight  = [];$result = getmxrr("googlemail.com", $mxHosts, $weight);var_dump($result, $mxHosts, $weight);'
    bool(true)
    array(0) {
    }
    array(0) {
    }`